# How to remove word from the string in a generic way

Tags: c#

I have a string which is basically a url something like APIPAth/resources/customers/SSNNumber/authorizations/contracts.

The SSNNumber can be of any value. Its the actual SSN number which I want to remove from the string and the string should look like APIPAth/resources/customers/authorizations/contracts.

I can't find a proper solution in which without hardcoding the word and removing the string

I tried using Find and Replace but I think the function would require the particular word

Comment: The concept you're looking for is a regular expression.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault seems like there's a juxtaposition of the requirements. You call it an ssn, but then say it can be of any value. Is there a specific format it has to be? Is it always at a certain position in the url? How can we identify it?

Comment: I added SSNNumber as an example. The string will contain a person's SSNNumber which different for each person and I am trying to remove it from the string. The string will always contain "APIPAth/resources/customers/" and "/authorizations/contracts." before and after the SSN Number. My aim is to remove the unique SSN Number from the string

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the URL you provided, it appears you only want to get rid of digits. You could accomplish that with this line:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"[\d]", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin this cat depending on what stays static.

One way would be to split the url by separators and join them back

```
var url = @"APIPAth/resources/customers/SSNNumber/authorizations/contracts";
var items = new List<string>(url.Split('/'));
items.RemoveAt(3);
url = string.Join("/", items);
```

Another way would be to use `Regex`

```
var url = @"APIPAth/resources/customers/SSNNumber/authorizations/contracts";
url = Regex.Replace(url, @"/customers/[^/]+/authorizations/", "/customers/authorizations/")
```

If you elaborate on what you expect in a generic solution, i.e. what part stays static, then I can help you out better

Answer (score 0):

If SSN in number then it has to have form of this `000 00 0000` means `9 digits` consequents.
Took a string parse it by `/` and you get an array of elements lets say `parsed`

```
for(int i=0; i<parsed.length; i++){
  if(parsed[i].length === 9){
    ...keep this i...
  }
}
```

remove this parsed[i] from whole parsed and concat with `/`